# Logout is not working in Firebase with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, logout

Using firebase for user auth, sign up and login is working well, but logout is not working and don't know how to check. Here is my code

**Logout.js**

```
 const { currrentUser, logout } = useAuth();

  const handleLogout = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setError("");
    try {
      await logout();
      navigate("/login");
    } catch {
      setError("Failed to logout");
    }
  };

<div className="btn-container">
   <button onClick={() => setLogoutModal(false)}>Cancel</button>
   <button onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</button>
</div>
```

**Auth.js**

```
 function logout() {
    return auth().signOut();
  }
```

*Feel free to ask more details*

Comment: @Dharmaraj can you help with this, please?

Answer (score 0):

Although in many documentations, `signOut()` function took no argument. I changed `signOut()` in Auth.js to `signOut(auth)`.  And now it works.